# Python regex to match 6-digit numbers of different formats

Tags: python, regex

I need to find and capture all occurrences of 6 digit numbers with OMIM and MIM prefixes and all 6 digit numbers where there is no preceding colon.

### Expected output

```py
[111111, 222222, 555555, 444444]
```

### What I have tried

```py
import re

sentence = '111111;Dystonia-1,222222,OMIM:555555; 3333333 Dystonic disorder1,MIM#444444'

re1 = r'OMIM:(\d{6})'
re2 = r'MIM#(\d{6})'
re3 = r'[^:](\d{6})'

identifiers = re.compile("(%s|%s|%s)" % (re1, re2, re3)).findall(sentence)
```

### Current output

```py
[
  ( ',222222'     , ''       , ''       , '222222' ),
  ( 'OMIM:555555' , '555555' , ''       , ''       ),
  ( ' 333333'     , ''       , ''       , '333333' ),
  ( 'MIM#444444'  , ''       , '444444' , ''       )
]
```

Comment: Is your question why you got a list of tuples instead of a list of numbers, or why `111111` is not matched?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you could try:

```
\b(?:MIM#|OMIM:|(?<!:))(\d{6})\b
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYq7ci/1)

- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `(?:` - Non-capture group:

  - `MIM#|OMIM:|(?<!:)` - Literally "MIM#" or "OMIM:" or a negative lookbehind to assert position is not preceded by a colon.
  - `)`. Close non-capture group.
- `(\d{6})` - Capture six digits in a capture group.
- `\b` - Word boundary.

---

```
import re
sentence = '111111;Dystonia-1,222222,OMIM:555555; 3333333 Dystonic disorder1,MIM#444444'
print(re.findall(r'\b(?:MIM#|OMIM:|(?<!:))(\d{6})\b', sentence))
```

Prints:

```
['111111', '222222', '555555', '444444']
```